# Complex multi level hierarchical SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I achieve the below results using a query in SQL Server.

Table: shares_info

Complex multilevel hierarchy:

```
comp_name investee

APPLE     MS
APPLE     INTEL
APPLE     MRF
APPLE     GOOG
MS        GOOG
MS        MRF
MRF       STF
MRF       ABC
GOOG      INTEL
GOOG      TRF
GOOG      XYZ
```

The idea is something like this. APPLE has invested in MS,INTEL,MRF,GOOG. And so on. Now the below input is something like sell my shares but first sell off shares without dependencies first. That is what my output conveys. If I want to sell GOOG shares then based on my below input GOOG has dependency on INTEL/TRF/XYZ and hence before selling GOOG I need to sell (123, XYZ) and (456 INTEL). Next, if I want to sell APPLE it has dependency on MS/INTEL/MRF/GOOG and hence as per below input I need to first sell INTEL/MRF/GOOG to sell off APPLE.

Table: shares_sell_info

Some input

```
id  comp_name

123 APPLE
456 APPLE
123 XYZ
789 GOOG
456 INTEL
243 MRF
432 ABC
```

The ordering should be like below

```
123 XYZ  (XYZ does not have any dependency and hence should come at the top)
432 ABC (MRF has a dependency on ABC and hence ABC comes on top)
243 MRF (MRF’s dependency is all taken care and hence we have MRF)
456 INTEL (APPLE and GOOGLE has a dependency on INTEL and hence INTEL is on top)
789 GOOG (At this point we can add GOOG because all its dependents are already at top)
123 APPLE (APPLE has a dependency on GOOG and hence GOOG come before APPLE)
456 APPLE
```

In the above ordering one among XYZ/ABC could have been first and it does not matter because they both do not have any dependency

Comment: I fail to understand the logic. Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: I hope my additional explanation is good enough?

Comment: @Jithu . . . I don't think you can guarantee that there are no cycles.  How are these handled?  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm sure in our case there wouldn't be any cycles. Eg. If Apple invested in GOOG then we will not have a row where GOOG invested in APPLE. This is guaranteed.

Comment: Interesting question. +1

Comment: @Jithu I think the solution would require nested recursive CTEs. As far as I know, only PostgreSQL implements them. Unfortunately SQL Server does not implement these kind of CTEs.

Comment: Here is the actual answer for this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420380/assign-weight-based-on-hierarchical-depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the actual answer for my problem that I got from another post.

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420380/assign-weight-based-on-hierarchical-depth`

Answer (score 0):

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f4b5354b7f1a6abd780bb2e0cc83891)

```
WITH 
 cte_com as (SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(123 ,'APPLE'),
(456 ,'APPLE'),
(123 ,'XYZ'),
(789 ,'GOOG'),
(456 ,'INTEL'),
(243 ,'MRF'),
(432 ,'ABC')) as cte_com(id, comp))
,cte_temp as (SELECT * FROM (VALUES
 ('APPLE',     'MS'),  
 ('APPLE',     'INTEL' ),
 ('APPLE',     'MRF' ),
 ('APPLE',     'GOOG' ),
 ('MS',        'GOOG' ),
 ('MS',        'MRF' ),
 ('MRF',       'STF' ),
 ('MRF',       'ABC' ),
 ('GOOG',      'INTEL' ),
 ('GOOG',      'TRF' ),
 ('GOOG',      'XYZ')) as cte_temp(one, two))


 SELECT id, comp , one
     , count(*) as count
 from cte_com
 left join cte_temp on cte_temp.one=cte_com.comp
 group by id, comp, one
 order by count(*)
```

But it's unclear why this solution gives the ordering you want.

What is the difference between 'XYZ' and 'ABC'?
They are both depending on 1 other comp.

output:

```
id  comp    one count
123 XYZ             1
432 ABC             1
456 INTEL           1
243 MRF     MRF     2
789 GOOG    GOOG    3
123 APPLE   APPLE   4
456 APPLE   APPLE   4
7 rows
```

Comment: I just updated my post to elaborate more. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Luuk's idea is right with some slight modifications. Here is the query which worked for me.

```
select * from shares_sell_info as ssi
left join (
select comp_name, count(*) as count
    from shares_info si
    group by comp_name
UNION
select comp_name, 0 as count
    from shares_info
    where investee is null
) temp on temp.comp_name = share_info.comp_name
where id in (
            )
order by count
```

Comment: `temp on temp.comp_name = share_info.comp_name` should probably be `temp on temp.comp_name = ssi.comp_name.`     
`where id in ()` is throwing an error.

Comment: I gave it a thought and this will not solve the full problem. I'm going to give it some more thought on the solution and post it once I have it.