# Assign weight based on hierarchical depth

Tags: sql, sql-server

Take a table with values like below with two columns. I want the output in such a way that the count should be based on the depth of the hierarchy. Eg. A has a dependency on B,D and B has a dependency on C (C has not dependency) and D has dependencies on B,E and E has dependency on C and hence the weight of A is 6.

```
A B
A D
B C
D B
D E
E C
```

```
A 6
B 1
C 0
D 4
E 1
```

How can I write a SQL server query to achieve this output.

Comment: I think the count for "A" should be 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think does what you want:

```
with cte as (
      select col1, col2
      from t
      union all
      select cte.col1, t.col2
      from cte join 
           t
           on t.col1 = cte.col2
      )
select col1, sum(w)
from (select cte.col1, col2, 1 as w
      from cte
      union all
      select col2, null, 0
      from t
     ) t
group by col1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3dab8dec74e1689a547f2c39a4103975) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cte for this:

```
select 
  child=cast(child as varchar(10)),
  parent=cast(parent as varchar(10))
into #dat
from (values 
  ('A','B'),('A','D'),('B','C'),('D','B'),('D','E'),('E','C')
) x (child,parent)

;with cte 
as (
  select distinct
    parent as node,
    0 as level,
    parent as chain,
    isleaf = case when exists (select 1 from #dat dpy where dpy.child=dp.parent) then 1 else 0 end
  from #dat dp 
  where not exists (select 1 from #dat dpx where dp.parent=dpx.child)

  union all

  select
    dc.child,
    c.level+1,
    cast(c.chain+dc.child as varchar(10)),
    isleaf = case when exists (select 1 from #dat dcx where dcx.parent=dc.child) then 1 else 0 end
  from #dat dc
  join cte c
    on c.node=dc.parent

)

select 
  node, sum(level) 
from cte
group by node
```

result:

```
node    weight
A   8
B   1
C   0
D   4
E   1
```

result of just `select * from cte` gives you structure overview:

```
node  level  chain  isleaf
C     0      C      0
B     1      CB     1
E     1      CE     1
D     2      CED    1
A     3      CEDA   0
A     2      CBA    0
D     2      CBD    1
A     3      CBDA   0
```